# Format table to text output in C#

Tags: c#, sql, text, output, tabular

I have a query versus an SQL database in C#. From this query I get a List like:

```
List<List<string>>()
```

this list can be changed to any other table type if required..

In Microsoft Server Management Studio it looks like this:

[image]

In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can simply output the result as text, which looks like this:

[image]

Now as I am automating some tasks I will use C# rather than manually using MSSQL. Due to a GXP environment it is important to have every datachange in the Database Documented separately with a text report attached to a "ticket".

For now my query with Table Text generation looks like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT '" + description + "' AS '" + description + "', CPPS_Site,Study_Id,CustNo,CPPS_Job FROM CDS.dbo.Studies " +
                                            "WHERE Study_Id = " + studyID, con);
List<string> overview = new List<string>();

overview.Add("|=========================================================|");
overview.Add("|"+description + "\t|CPPS_Site\t|Study_ID\t|CustNo\t|CPPS_Job|");
overview.Add("|---------------------------------------------------------|");
using (SqlDataReader resultQuery = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    var schemaTable = resultQuery.GetSchemaTable();
    while (resultQuery.Read())
    {
        string build = "|";
        build +=  resultQuery.GetSqlValue(0) + "\t|"
              + resultQuery.GetSqlValue(1) + "\t\t|"
              + resultQuery.GetSqlValue(2) + "\t\t|"
              + resultQuery.GetSqlValue(3) + "\t|"
              + resultQuery.GetSqlValue(4);
        build += "|";
        overview.Add(build);
     }
overview.Add("|=========================================================|");
     return overview;
 }
```

Result:

[image]

while this is technically working and would also be accepted, I am personally very unpleased with this ugly solution. For instance with strings of different length, the format will not fit anymore. Do you know a more clean solution?

Comment: This Nuget package might do what you want: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DanielStout.AsciiTableFormatter/

Comment: and how do i use that? Im not familar with IEnumerable and I only find an example for manual use

Comment: I think you **are** familiar with `IEnumerable`. You just don't know it... :-)

Comment: thx for this advice.. i still cannot built something out of what i dont know

Comment: You could make a class with your 5 fields, add intance of this class per while-loop into the list (just like you do for the strings). And then give the list to the asciitableformatter package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Composite string formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/txafckwd(v=vs.90)) provides an aligment component that can be used to specify a field size and align values left or right. For example

```
String.Format("|{0,5}",5);
```

will produce

```
|    5|
```

Each line can be written as :

```
var linePattern="|{0,-7}|{1,-17}|{2,-11}|{3,-14}|{4,-8}|";
var line= String.Format(linePattern
    resultQuery.GetSqlValue(0),
    resultQuery.GetSqlValue(1),
    resultQuery.GetSqlValue(2),
    resultQuery.GetSqlValue(3),
    resultQuery.GetSqlValue(4));
```

The header can be written using the same pattern:

```
var header=String.Format(linePattern,"Before","CPPS_Site","Study_ID","CustNo","CPPS_Job");
```

Writing both the header and line to the console will appear like this :

```
|Before |CPPS_Site        |Study_ID   |CustNo        |CPPS_Job|
|Before |1                |2          |C50030        |999     |
```

If the strings are larger than the field values though, they won't be truncated and the format will appear broken, eg:

```
|Before |CPPS_Site        |Study_ID   |CustNo        |CPPS_Job|
|Before123 |1                |2          |C50030        |999     |
```

Comment: the broken format unfortunately is exactly the issue I have. but looks like something i can build on

Comment: @julianbechtold in this case you'd have to load all data in order to calculate field lengths. Perhaps you could load everything into a DataTable, or read the first eg 100 rows and use them to calculate field lengths